# Nest.js unique dto validator

Tags: node.js, express, class, validation, nestjs

Maybe someone know how to make custom unique validator with class-validator in nest.js.I found few articles in internet, but however those implementations was not reusable. I wanna my unique validator reuse in every dto for example: users, products.

Comment: Do you mean unique from database?

Comment: That unique validator should go check in database and if there nothing found than should pass validation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this small lib to reach your goal or get inspired by it's code
[dbvalidator](https://github.com/AyubTouba/nestjs-dbvalidator),

to use it, you only need to, install it `npm install @youba/nestjs-dbvalidator`

2/ register it :

```
 @Module({
  imports: [DbValidatorsModule.register({
    type: 'mysql',
    host:  "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    username:"root",
    password:"password",
    database:"demo"})],
  providers: [StreetService],
  controllers: [StreetController],
})
export class StreetModule {
  constructor() {}
}
```

3/ use it in DTO :

```
@IsNotEmpty()
@Validate(IsUnique, 
[ { table: "company", column: "name" }] )
 name: string;
```

*ps:I'm the author in case you need any explanation*

Answer (score 0):

Youba!
There is an error in your module if we use camelCase:

```
@Validate(IsUnique, [{ table: 'customers', column: 'carName' }])
```

As example,

```
query: "select carName from customers where  carName like 'Scoda1'",
parameters: undefined,
driverError: error: column "carname" does not exist
```